How best to replace pole barn nailed pickets?
I'm dealing with a 85' foot long fence with 6' cedar pickets that need to be replaced. The previous owner assembled it with both "pole barn"  nails and the occasional screw. Screws are easy to remove. Those nails, though, are tough to get at when the head is sunken into the picket. Banging on the backside of the picket, I expect, is not good for the frame. How can I remove the nails/pickets without damaging the frame?

There are nail pullers for this.
They have pincher claws that dig in under the head to pull out nails.  They dig in with a hammer slide.

Picture from amazon, just for seeing.

Picture from Amazon...  I think you're really Jeff Bezos.  :-)

Thanks for the lead. I'll see what I can do.

@JACK  I wish.  Just hope I did the picture right.

I ended up with a nail puller - not quite so rugged but sufficiently effective. Thanks again.
